# deployment of code in different repo

Tags: maven, jenkins, plsql

currently I have the code in my dev env. And after compiling and testing I want to move it to staging env from jenkins. I am not sure how to accomplish this goal using maven commands. Any idea on it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean with different repo? A source code repository or a Maven repository?

Comment: source code repository

Comment: Than you are not talking about deployment. Usually deployments means to transfer an built artifact into a repository (Maven repo). But not source code. You can of course transfer artfacts (binary artifacts) from one repository into a different stage (This can be achieved with repository managers)..like Nexus etc. And apart from that Maven is a build tool...Maybe you can give more details...

Comment: Well, the project is a plsql project. I have it in my dev env. Then the project is linked to jenkins via SVN, which builds and tests the project. From here I want to move the project to staging env and further to production env. Any suggestions as to how I can get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are sure that you have tested your code on Dev Environment, than why do you want to transfer the source code into any other area.
1. Source code repo keeps track using branches/tags
2. To transfer the artefacts using Jenkins you can simply use execute shell.
  A) Download the artefact from dev environment using wget into jenkins workspace
  B) upload the same into staging repository

Comment: Well, the project is a plsql project. I have it in my dev env. Then the project is linked to jenkins via SVN, which builds and tests the project. From here I want to move the project to staging env and further to production env. Any suggestions as to how I can get it done.